# Spliting string, flatMapping it and creating objects using Java streams?

Tags: java, java-stream, flatmap

I have 2 classes going like this:

```
public class Seat extends Moviefiable {

        private int number;
        private Hall hall;

        public Seat(int id, boolean active, int number, Hall hall) {
            super(id, active);
            this.number = number;
            this.hall = hall;
        }

        public Seat() {this(-1, false, -1, null);}

        public static Seat getById(int idSeat) throws SQLException {
            Seat seat = SeatDAO.getById(idSeat);
            return seat;
        }
}

public class Ticket extends Moviefiable {

private Projection projection;
private Seat seat;
private LocalDateTime purchasingDate;
private User user;

public Ticket(int id, boolean active, Projection projection, Seat seat, LocalDateTime purchasingDate, User user) {
    super(id, active);
    this.projection = projection;
    this.seat = seat;
    this.purchasingDate = purchasingDate;
    this.user = user;
}

public Ticket() {this(-1, false, null, null, null, null);}
```

Now, I need to create two or more `Tickets`, depending how many tickets `loggedInUser` chooses. From my `JSP` page, I'll get something like this:

```
String uri = request.getQueryString(); //uri looks like this: seats=2&seats=3
```

I want to create two `Ticket` objects for two `Seat` objects. In `uri` string, chars 2 and 3 are primary keys for seats.

The idea is to use Java streams to perform splitting and creating objects. This is I have so far.

```
ArrayList<Ticket> newTicketsForSeats = Stream.of(uri.split("&"))
                   .map(s -> s.split("seats=")[1])
                   //.flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                   .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
                   .mapToObj(s -> {
                    try {
                        return new Ticket(-1, true, projection, SeatDAO.getById(s), 
                                 LocalDateTime.now(), loggedInUser);
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                   .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

When I made a test, like this to see the output I'm getting:

```
Stream.of(uri.split("&"))
    .map(s -> s.split("seats=")[1])
    .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
    .forEach(System.out::println); //2 3
```

Which is okey. But when I run code above, I got:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at servlets.ConfirmPurchaseServlet.lambda$0(ConfirmPurchaseServlet.java:62)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
```

`projection` is also object, which I obtained, this is just reference, it is elsewhere in servlet. `loggedInUser` I got from session. I'm newbie regarding Java streams, any additional explanation would be excellent.

I get that `map()` requires `IntUnaryOperator` lambda expression, something like this:

```
s -> s * 10
```

I don't know how to "map" from int (primary key for Seat) to `Seat` object.

Cheers.

Comment: I think you need `mapToObj` instead of `map`...

Comment: I changed `map` to `mapToObj` and second `mapToObj` is reporting error: The method mapToObj((<no type> s) -> {}) is undefined for the type Stream<Seat>

Comment: Also posted here: https://coderanch.com/t/724831/java/Splitting-string-flatMapping-creating-objects

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are trying to assign the stream output to an `ArrayList`.  `Collectors.toList()` returns a `List` that cannot be expected to be a particular implementation.

So either do this:

```
List<SomeClass> list = ...collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or this

```
ArrayList<SomeClass> list = ... collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

The following should work but it may need some tweaking based on your other classes.

```
ArrayList<Ticket> newTicketsForSeats = Stream.of(uri.split("&"))
               .map(s -> s.split("seats="))
               .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
               .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
               .mapToObj(s -> new Ticket(-1, true, projection, SeatDAO.getById(s), 
                     LocalDateTime.now(), loggedInUser))
               .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your replay. I edited my original question. SeatDAO.getById(int idSeat) may throw an exception, so Eclipse itself suggested this try-catch block, tho, I'm getting some unchecked exception somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Either of these would probably work:

```
List<Ticket> newTicketsForSeats = Stream.of(uri.split("&"))
        .map(s -> s.replace("seats=", ""))
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
        .mapToObj(s -> new Ticket(-1, true, projection, SeatDAO.getById(s), LocalDateTime.now(), loggedInUser))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<Ticket> newTicketsForSeats = Stream.of(uri.split("&"))
        .map(s -> s.replace("seats=", ""))
        .map(s -> new Ticket(-1, true, projection, SeatDAO.getById(Integer.valueOf(s)), LocalDateTime.now(), loggedInUser))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

BTW: you don't seem to have a Ticket constructor which matches the signature:

```
Ticket(int, boolean, Projection, Seat, LocalDateTime, boolean)
```

Comment: Thank you Ron, for replying here and on Ranch forum. Internet sometimes, as odd it seems, may be a small place :) I edited my answer. Regarding Ticket constructor, I I have it my class goes like this: Ticket(int id, boolean active, Projection projection, Seat seat, LocalDateTime date, User user)Hope you can help me.

Comment: As a side note, you surely want `.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)` instead of `.mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)`, as otherwise, you’re boxing into an `Integer` object, just to unbox to an `int` immediately. If you don’t care about boxing overhead, use `.map(Integer::valueOf)`…